# How to "chain" modal dialogs in YUI 2?

Tags: dialog, yui, modal-dialog, widget

I have a modal dialog box presented in Yahoo UI. The user selects a value from dialog "A", and then I want to present another modal dialog box to collect some more data in dialog "B".

I have been using the YAHOO.widget.Dialog successfully. The problem seems to be that you can't initiate dialog window "B" from the handler function of dialog "A". So, how can you programmatically launch a second dialog window after the user hits the "OK" button on the first ?

(I had tried to create an additional Listener for a field that is updated in dialog "A" to trigger dialog "B" but this doesn't work either.)

Thanks..

Comment: That sounds broken. Perhaps you could 'get' around the limitation by using a setTimeout to open "B" after closing "A". Or, if you can close "A" in the handler, perhaps you could open "B" right after.

Comment: A timer is, unfortunately, inappropriate. User driven behaviour is required. And no it's not broken. It's a limitation of the framework. However, I am sure it's solvable, just need someone with more experience with YUI to point me in the right direction.

Comment: This seems like it should work - I guess I'm missing something in the question. I have a modal dialog (for editing some data) with save and cancel buttons. The save button's onclick function triggers a second "please wait" modal dialog.

Comment: Another option would be to change the dialog body content on clicking a button, rather than closing and triggering a new dialog.

Comment: @gavin. Interesting approach.hmm.. will give it a go.. thnx

Comment: Can you please post some code? Maybe the button handler code associated with dialog "A". Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the documentation: http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/container/dialog/#events.  The following code should do the trick:

```
var firstDialog = new YAHOO.widget.Dialog('firstDialog', { postmethod: "manual" });

firstDialog.manualSubmitEvent.subscribe(function (type, args) {

    var nextDialog = new YAHOO.widget.Dialog('nextDialog', {  });

    /* more configuration stuff... */

    nextDialog.render();
    nextDialog.show();

});

firstDialog.render();
firstDialog.show();
```

This handles when the form is to be submitted, which I think what you mean by selects a value, but if not let me know and I can give some help on that situation.

Comment: thanks for the pointer.. i never understood that "manualsubmitevent". YUI is quite powerful, but still needs more explicit doco.. will let you know